# На странице есть 2 поля ввода.В оба текстовые строки вводятся серия значений, разделенных запятой. при нажатии на кнопку должно исполниться функция

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице находится 2 поля ввода. В оба текстовые строки
вводятся серия значений, разделенных запятой (значение числовые). при
нажатии на кнопку должно исполниться функция. Функция формирует 2
массивы и их объединяет без повторов
мой код:

```
var array1 = [5, 2, 1, -10, 8];
var array2 = [5, 2, 1, -9, 3, 7];

var union = function(array1, array2) {
    var array3 = [];
    var arr = array1.concat(array2);
    var len = arr.length;
    var obj = {};

    while(len--) {
        var itm = arr[len];

        if(!obj[itm]) {
            array3.unshift(itm);
            obj[itm] = true;
        }
    }

    return array3;
};

document.writeln(union(array1, array2)); // [-10,8,5,2,1,-9,3,7]
```

**как сделать так чтобы эта функция объединяла не заданы заранее масиви.А массивы которые мы зададим в полях ввода?**

Comment: " эта функция обеднювала не заданы заранее масиви." --- сорри, но мы не понимать

Comment: считайте данные из инпутов и разбейте через разделитель данные за счет `.split(',')`  получится массив

Comment: Добавьте еще функцию, которая будет читать данные из полей ввода по нажатии на кнопку или еще как-то, конвертируйте данные в массивы и подставьте эти массивы в array1 и array2. Сама же функция могла быть гораздо проще, поместить все данные в Set, а затем через spread преобразовать в массив.

Comment: `arr3 = [... new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])];` - все, что надо для объединения двух массивов `arr1` и `arr2` без повторений.

Comment: @Leonid мне нужно чтобы объединяла массивы котрие которые образуются с помощью текстовых полей

Comment: @olooliver , пока ничего в вашем коде не получает данные из полей ввода. Добавьте поле ввода в виде html-разметки, добавьте соответствующего слушателя в код, адаптируйте полученные данные, как указали выше (с помощью split). Если что-то не получится - пишите, размещайте новый код, посмотрим, поможем.